# HTML form with multiple action. 1 for PHP and another for an API

Tags: php, html, post

Hi I have form that start like this:

```
<form id="SignupForm" action="results.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-vertical">
```

The values entered within the form's section will need to be processed on the results.php.

However I also need to pass the values of the fields within the form section into a 3rd party application via an API that goes like this:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://thirdpartysite.com/apikey"
method="post">
```

How can I do this? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

form elements are not designed to send its data to multiple actions, the only way would be to send your data to the api in your `results.php` with php or you send your data after the submit was triggered with javascript and then submit the form.

javascript (jquery)

```
$('#SignupForm').on('submit', function(e){
    // don't e.preventDefault - let the ajax event be async false 
    // so your form gets submited after the ajax request was finished

    var self = $(this);
    //send to api wait for response
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://thirdpartysite.com/apikey',
        data: self.serialize(),
        async: false
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to intercept the forms submit event and then post the information to your own script and the third party script.

A quick (untested) jquery example:

```
$('myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    // prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {}; // This would be the actual form data

    // post to your script
    $.post('/myscript.php', formData);

    // post to third party
    $.post('thirdPartySite', formData);
});
```

Comment: what will the contents be of formData? I mean what will I give to formData variable

Answer (score 0):

you may put a CURL request in your results.php that sends values to https://thirdpartysite.com/apikey